# Wildcard in variable list

Tags: sas

```
totalSUPPLY= sum(of supply1-supply485);
```

Ive got this simple calculation to make (in SAS) from a table that Ive transposed (hence the variable names). I have to do this several times, and the the number of supply variables is not the same for each calculation. I.e. in the above example its 485, but I do it later in my analysis and its 350.

My question: Is there a way to 'wildcard' the number of 'supply' columns. Basically, I want something like this (but this doesnt work): `totalSUPPLY= sum(of supply1-supply%);`

Also: If there is an easier way do the same Im open (and would actually prefer) that.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Why is the [tag:sql] tag on this question?

Comment: I put the SQL tag on because I thought that someone with experience in both SAS and SQL might be able to solve my little problem.

Comment: Please don't add [tag:sql] unless you're asking a question that specifically includes sql language; it's confusing, and in addition it causes the [tag:sql] to show up as the label in the google results (since it takes the more popular tag).  If it's a SAS question that a SQL-but-not-SAS person couldn't answer, don't include it.

Answer (score 2):

```
data yoursummary;
  set yourdata; /*dataset containing supply1-supply485*/
  array supplies{*} supply:;
  totalSUPPLY = sum(of supplies{*});
run;
```

N.B. using a `:` wildcard like this will only pick up matching variables that are present in the PDV at the point when you create the array, so the array definition has to come after the set statement. Also, it only works for variables with a common prefix, not those with a common suffix.

As Joe has pointed out, the following more concise code also works:

```
data yoursummary;
  set yourdata; /*dataset containing supply1-supply485*/
  totalSUPPLY = sum(of supplies:);
run;
```

Of course, if you declare an array it's then easier to do related things like checking how many variables are being added together, or looping through the variables in the array and applying the same logic to each one in turn.

Comment: You don't have to use an array here; you can simply say `totalSUPPLY=sum(of supply:);`.